# Android Disable showing soft-keyboard on selecting text

Tags: android

on EditText when i select text, soft-keyboard show automatically by android, how can i disable showing keyboard on selecting text?

i found many solution about hide or disable showing keyboard, but i can't find any solution about disable that on selecting text. is any solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want keyboard when you click in edit text that means you do not want it to be editable. To do so disable the `edittext`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hello there I am edit text"
    android:enabled="false"/>
```

when you get into the condition when you want it to be enabled, enable it from code

```
edittext.setEnabled(true);
```

But the chances are that your use case might be valid for usage of `TextView`. Because if you dont want keyboard, it means you do not want to edit it by typing, which is what `Textview` Does.

Comment: yes you have right, but on selecting text i dont like to have soft-keyboard please review my post

Comment: yes, i want to editing text and on long click to select text i want to don't have soft-keyboard